# UIWebView can't open my HTTPS URL

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uiwebview, ios6.1

I want to open a HTTPS URL with my `UIWebView`. I already add the code which `allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost`. It's a simple request with my `NSURLRequest`, it seems it was successful but nothings is shown in my iPhone.

And when I try to connect using my 3g this log appears:

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate(webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: _kCFURLConnectionPrivateRunLoopMode
```

I tried to add couple codes but none of them worked:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

@implementation NSURLRequest (NSURLRequestWithIgnoreSSL)

+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Any ideas of what is happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the certificate for your SSL server self-signed or signed by a trusted certificate authority?

Comment: @MarcusAdams It's server self-signed

Comment: @MarcusAdams I tried that too, but my webView still blank.